# Can't connect to 802.1x network on "rMBP 2014" using Windows 8.1 through bootcamp

Tags: bootcamp, windows, 802.1x

I installed Windows 8.1 using Boot Camp on my new rMBP 13" 2014.
In OS X I can connect to the network in my company but when I'm in Windows I can't.

It gives me a popup after I entered my credentials and ask's me if I want to accept the certificate. I do. Then after some time it just says it can't connect.

I searched for this problem and came across people who had experience the same, but they were on older rMBP and the solution they offered was to use [older network adapter drivers](http://www.msitgeek.com/fixing-windows-8-wifi-issues-in-bootcamp/).
Because my macbook is recently released, there aren't any other drivers available.

Anybody got a workaround for this problem?
Before you say "just stay on OS X": I can't. I'm a .NET developer ;) .

Comment: It wasn't the solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I did resolve the problem by approaching the same solution as the guy did. Which was going to the website of the manufacturer and download the most recent driver and now it's resolved.